# How do I use MUI's shadows?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to add a shadow to a `<Grid container>` component.

I see in the documentation [here](https://mui.com/system/shadows/#main-content). I should just use something like `boxShadow={1}` and import `import { shadows } from '@material-ui/system';`.

I've done this, but am not getting any results.

Would anyone know the correct way to add shadows to a component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `<Grid />` doesn't have the props `boxShadow`,

Use `<Box />` with its component as Grid would be fine.

```
<Box
  component={Grid}
  container
  boxShadow={3}
>
  <Box ... />
  <Box ... />
  ...
</Box>
```

---

Refer:

- MUI [Box props API](https://material-ui.com/components/box/)
- MUI [Grid props API](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/)

---

Demo and source:

```
<Box
  component={Grid}
  container
  boxShadow={3}
  spacing={3}
  style={{ padding: 10 }}
>
  <Box component={Grid} item boxShadow={0} xs={3}>
    boxShadow={0}
  </Box>
  <Box component={Grid} item boxShadow={1} xs={3}>
    boxShadow={1}
  </Box>
  <Box component={Grid} item boxShadow={2} xs={3}>
    boxShadow={2}
  </Box>
  <Box component={Grid} item boxShadow={3} xs={3}>
    boxShadow={3}
  </Box>
</Box>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In **MUI v5**, all MUI components have [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) support now. You can add a `boxShadow` value directly without having to import the `shadows` array:

```
<Stack direction="row" gap={2}>
  <Box sx={{ boxShadow: 10, width: 30, height: 30 }} />
  <Button sx={{ boxShadow: 10 }}>button</Button>
  <Chip sx={{ boxShadow: 10 }} label="chip" />
  <CircularProgress sx={{ boxShadow: 10, borderRadius: 50 }} />
</Stack>
```

Many `sx` properties are [theme aware](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#theme-aware-properties), including `boxShadow`. The code below:

```
sx={{ boxShadow: 10 }}
```

Is the same as:

```
sx={{ boxShadow: theme => theme.shadows[10] }}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]